# Cordova 3.3 Android app crashes on orientation change while there is a text selection in any text field.

Tags: android, cordova, webview, cordova-3

This is not another question on the orientation change related app crashing. I have a particular scenario. If there is a text selection in any of the text fields and an orientation change occurs then the app crashes.

I looked at a few proposed solutions online that said that I need to get out  the "screenSize" from `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"` 
in the Manifest file. This causes the app to crash with even without having text selected in the text fields.

The other proposed fix was changing the sdk version to anything above 14. Mine is 17.

Did not find any app facing the similar problem like mine.

The log is as below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.invalidate(ActionBarImpl.java:900)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.showSelectActionBar(ContentViewCore.java:2133)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.access$2100(ContentViewCore.java:85)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore$12.showHandles(ContentViewCore.java:2048)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectionHandleController.onSelectionChanged(SelectionHandleController.java:168)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.onSelectionBoundsChanged(ContentViewCore.java:2462)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
W/System.err( 7550):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 7550):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 7550):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
W/System.err( 7550):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7550):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
W/System.err( 7550):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
W/System.err( 7550):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Post some code and also, what is line num 900 of ActionBarImpl.java class ??

Comment: `This is not another question on the orientation change related app crashing` - yes it is. `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale` as long as you have this hack in your manifest, you will have problems.  Remove it and try again.  Your app will crash but post the new logcat and it will show us exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Guys thanks for help. I resolved the issue. I was calling the actionMode.finish() manually which is apparently already called by android. But would like to know the issue with android:configChanges.